# Multiplication of Integer by double and storing result as a double

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

Out of plain curiosity, in swift:

```
var a:Double = 3.5
var b:Int = 4
var c = a * Double(b)
var d:Double = a * b
```

Why is `d` not valid but `c` is? Since I'm specifying that `d` is a double, shouldn't the compiler detect that `b` should be casted to a double?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift, you must explicitly **convert** types, instead of **cast** it. [See the document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID326).

> Because each numeric type can store a different range of values, you must opt in to numeric type conversion on a case-by-case basis. This opt-in approach prevents hidden conversion errors and helps make type conversion intentions explicit in your code.

When you have `b:Int`, you can `Double(b)`, because it's conversion from `Int` to `Double`, but you cannot `b as Double` or `c: Double = b` because it's casting.

As for `var d:Double = a * b`, The problem is that there is no `*` operator implementation which accepts `Double` and `Int` as operands and returns `Double`.

If you want, you can implement overloaded operator:

```
func *(lhs:Double, rhs:Int) -> Double {
    return lhs * Double(rhs)
}

var d:Double = a * b // -> 14
```

But I don't recommend to do that. You should do explicit *conversion* instead.

Comment: -- The problem is that there is no `*` operator implementation which accepts `Double` and `Int` as operands and returns `Double`. I think that's the answer I was looking for but was curious as to why that wasn't the case.

Comment: Added quotation from the document. Maybe this is answering your question?

Answer (score 1):

Swift doesn't do automatic type conversion except in very precise cases, so, when mixing arithmetic types you have to explicitly handle the conversion.

Comment: Should note that this is _intentional_. It's not a missing feature or a bug, and Apple won't add it if you complain.